# String iteration matched to lookup table

Tags: python, python-3.x

A newbie question:  I have to iterate a name then associate each letter with a number beginning with `a=1, b=2, c=3, etc.` and then sum the numbers.  I've gotten this far but no farther:

```
def main():
    name = input("Enter name  ")
    sum = 0
    for ch in name:
        # ?
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
def main():
    print sum(ord(c.lower()) - ord('a') + 1 for c in raw_input("Enter name: "))
```

This will work even if you're dealing with both uppercase and lowercase letters. If you'll only be dealing with lowercase, you can change `c.lower()` to `c` (it will still work as is, of course, but making that change will make it faster if you are only working with lowercase letters).

Comment: I think this is the only one that actually does exactly what he wants.. (based on my understanding of what he wants...)

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary mapping characters to values, then use the `get()` method with a default of 0 on the current character.